# POI - Table of contents

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, tableofcontents

I use POI to generate a table of content in a existing document. But when I open it with Word, I receive this message :

> This document contains fields that may refer to other files. Do you
>   want to update the fields in this documents ?

Is it possible to avoid this message and to get the toc updated ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to suppress that message - it's a security consideration. Updating fields in a document without the knowledge of the user code allow unsafe code to execute. You have to either

- Allow the user to manually confirm (as is happening now)
- Open the document prior to handing it over to the user using Word Automation Services (part of on-premise SharePoint)
- Use Word Automation to open the document, force the field update, save and close, before handing it over to the user (in this case, you do NOT set the "dirty" option)
- Incorporate an AutoOpen macro into the document (it will then need to be a docm rather than a docx) that updates the fields when the document is opened (again, don't set the "dirty" option)

You'll find more information on this in Eric White's blog: http://ericwhite.com/blog/updating-the-toc-in-a-wordprocessingml-document-using-an-autoopen-macro/